# The Number of symmetric,PD, $8\times 8$ matrices

Tags: matrices

The Number of symmetric,Positive Definite, $8\times 8$ matrices having trace$=8$ and determinant$=1$ is

1. $0$
2. $1$.
3. $>1$ but finite.
4. $\infty$

I am not able to do this one.

Comment: Hint: diagonal matrices.

Comment: Yes, so Only $1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is pos. def. then its eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ are real and positive. Besides, we know (don't we?) that, for any matrix, $\sum \lambda_i = tr(A)$ and $\prod \lambda_i= |A|$. In our case, that means that we are restricted to $\sum \lambda_i =8$ and $\prod \lambda_i =1$... (can you go on from here? hint: arithmetic-geometric means and their properties)

Comment: Here AM=GM for $a_1,\dots,a_8$, does that mean $a_1=\dots=a_8$?

Comment: Yes, that the AM equals the GM implies that all terms are equal, which in this case implies that $\lambda_i=1$, which in turns implies that the matrix is the identity.